Fingering the gnomus
I figured out a fingering for the final four bars of the gnomus from pictures at an exhibition. However I'm not very satisfied, as it feels somehow bumpy.

Usually I have difficulties with fingering because of my rather small hands, but in this case the size of my hand is not an issue. I feel it is more the sheer number of different interval steps to perform and remember. I tried a lot of variants and finally came out with this, but the third bar of the velocissimo seems to twist my brain. Has anybody other fingerings I could try? Or does anybody see major misconceptions in my fingering?
Snippet is taken from ksnortum's engraving at ismlp.org
Source of engraving

I admit that I've not tested your fingering, but, nonetheless, I'm also afraid that there's little we can tell you: we don't have your fingers or your experience in practising, nor any knowledge about your learning or performing capabilities. Your fingering may be fine for some and awful to others, and not only depending on their hands. Meaning that the same goes on the other way around: we may give you suggestions that we may think as reliable and reasonable, but may not work for you on the long run. Maybe, your issue is just about finding a proper learning/practice method to get it.

@musicamante I see your objections. It's true that a fingering often fits only few players. But I hoped to see some alternatives. I can learn/practice different fingerings which may be equivalent for many pieces. However for this one I think subtle changes may make a big difference in speed one can reach.

The fingering below might work for you as is, but the intention is just to illustrate some strategies not present in the given version.

Overall strategy:
Minimize the number of hand-position shifts.
Specific techniques:

Taking the first LH note with RH

This frees up the LH hand — without impeding the RH — so that each finger can remain on its key, maintaining a single hand position, until m. 2 beat 2.

Crossing 4 over 5

This becomes possible with certain moves from a white key to a higher black key (in the right hand) or a lower one (in the left hand). At the end of m. 2, for example, the RH uses this technique, because it allows for the measure to begin 1-2-3-4-5 and then facilitates the arrival on 3 in the next measure.

Similar fingerings in LH and RH

This was not a specific consideration here, but is beneficial where it occurs. There are places where both hands play, fix example, 3-4 simultaneously (m. 2, beat 2) or where one hand plays 1-2 while the other plays 2-1 (such as m. 2, beat 1). Familiar finger combinations, especially across similar intervals, can greatly benefit speed.

Repeated/sliding fingers (not used here)

One possibility that I chose not to use but which can work is to use the same finger twice consecutively by sliding from a black key to a white key. For example, in m. 2, moving from beat 2 to beat 3, it's possible to slide finger 4 from B♭ to A♮, facilitating the move of finger 3 to the measure's final B♭.
This technique is very fast, but can be hard to control and articulate cleanly.

First of all, sorry for not responding to your answer instantly. Your answer is a really great one. While it can't answer my question directly, as @musicamante already had anticipated it gives a great load of tips to improve fingering and variations to try. I'm still working on it and already found some clues. I'm sure the principle you have laid out here will help others as well.
